# Diference between registerColumnType and registerHibernateType

Tags: java, hibernate

I am triyng for the first time to extend an Hibernate dialog (PostgreSQL82Dialect). After reading documentation, I still don't understand.

What is the difference between `registerColumnType` and `registerHibernateType`?

Please give some hints?

Answer (score 0):

`registerHibernateType` is used to define a default type that hibernate supports.

`registerColumnType`  can register a type for the given type code and maximum column length. In other words, registerColumnType  is more detaild to define a sql-type.